# Tensorflow, tf.gradients calculations

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am learning how to use Tensorflow and at this 1 particular point I am really stuck and can not make a sense around it. Imagine I have a 5 layer network and the output is represented by `output`. Now suppose I want to find the gradient of `output` with respect to `layer_2`. For that purpose, the code I will write in Tensorflow will be something like:

```
gradients_i_want = tf.gradients(output, layer_2)
```

Theoretically, this gradient should be calculated via chain rule. I want to ask, that whether Tensorflow calculates these gradients via chain rule or it will just take the derivative of `output` with respect to `layer_2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow will create a graph for your model, where each node is an operation (e.g. addition, multiplication, or a combination of them). Basic ops have manually defined gradient functions, and those functions will be used when applying the chain rule while traveling backwards through the graph.

If you write your own custom op, you might need to also write the corresponding gradient function.